# Dynamically generating buttons from array android studio

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

i am trying to code a method that generates buttons with data it gets from a 2D array of names and IDs, the function should then add more buttons after already generated ones if run twice. The buttons are to be added to a constraint layout (using guidelines 18 and 19 that are part of the activities XML).

I am using a global list of buttons to store already generated button

```
List<Button> contactButtonList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then here is the function i have written to generate the buttons and attach them to the guide lines.

```
 void updateButtonList(String[][] contactsArray){

    //gets constraint layout
    ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
    //creates constraint set
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    //loops through array
    for(int i = 0; i < contactsArray.length; i++){

        //creates string to display on button
        String buttonText = contactsArray[i][0]+": "+contactsArray[i][1];
        //creates new button and sets ID based of size of list
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(contactButtonList.size());
        //sets button text from array
        btn.setText(buttonText);

        //adds the button to the layout
        layout.addView(btn,contactButtonList.size());

        //sets the constraint set to match the current layout.... i think?, this needs to be done after adding the view
        set.clone(layout);

        //connects button to left vert constraint
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.guideline19, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);


        //if first button attaches to horz constraint else attaches to last button
        if(contactButtonList.isEmpty()){
            set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.guideline18, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
        }else{
            set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, contactButtonList.get(contactButtonList.size() - 1).getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        }

        //adds button to list
        contactButtonList.add(btn);
    }

    //apply set to layout
    set.applyTo(layout);
}
```

Sorry if thats a bit lengthy, i hope the comments help.

Any way the problem is only the last button in the array is attached to the guidelines, the outher 2 just appear in the top left.

For example when using this array.

```
 String[][] testArray = {{"a","123"},{"bill","245"},{"test","246"}};
```

The output looks like (please ignore the text view and purple button).
[image: result]

when all the buttons are supposed to appear below each other.

I am assuming the first button is hidden behind the second in the top left.

Comment: I think that you are wiping out the _ConstraintSet_ each time through the loop. Try moving `set.clone(layout)` outside the `for` loop and after `ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet()`. If you respond here, tag me (@Cheticamp) so I will see the comment.

Comment: @Cheticamp I think you have the right idea but if i call `set.clone(layout)` before the loop only the first button appears, i fixed the problem by calling `set.applyTo(layout)` at the end of every iteration of the loop as so that it doesn't matter if the _ConstraintSet_ is wiped as it has already been applied.

Comment: `set.applyTo(layout)` is outside the loop in your posted code. It would be helpful if you would post the most recent code (if changed).

Comment: @Cheticamp code has changed quite a bit since but will see what i can do getting a version similar to the one in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution moving `set.applyTo(layout)` inside of the for loop, i also changed `btn.setId(contactButtonList.size());` to `btn.setId(View.generateViewId());` but im not sure if this contributed towards fixing the problem.
Here is the working code (note i have also added some features but these can be ignored).

```
void updateButtonList(final String[][] contactsArray){

    //gets constraint layout
    ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
    //creates constraint set
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    //loops through array
    for(int i = 0; i < contactsArray.length; i++){

        //creates string to display on button
        String buttonText = contactsArray[i][0]+": "+contactsArray[i][1];
        //creates new button and sets ID based of size of list
        Button btn = new Button(this);

        //sets layout params width as 0 so we can set to match constraint
        btn.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
        //sets button text from array
        btn.setText(buttonText);

        //sets color of button based of pos in list (red for even blue for odd)
        if((contactButtonList.size()%2) == 0) {
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
        }else{
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button);
        }

        //adds the button to the layout
        layout.addView(btn,contactButtonList.size());

        //sets the constraint set to match the current layout.... i think?, this needs to be done after adding the view
        set.clone(layout);

        //sets button width to match constraint
        set.constrainDefaultWidth(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_SPREAD);

        //connects button to left vert constraint
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.guideline19, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);
        //connects button to right ver constraint
        set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.guideline20, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 8);

        //if first button attaches to horz constraint else attaches to last button
        if(contactButtonList.isEmpty()){
            set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.guideline18, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
        }else{
            set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, contactButtonList.get(contactButtonList.size() - 1).getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        }

        //adds button to list
        contactButtonList.add(btn);
        //adds id to list
        contactIdList.add(contactsArray[i][1]);

        //apply set to layout
        set.applyTo(layout);
    }


}
```